# How to reinstall RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, rvm, uninstallation

I'm trying to do the One Month Rails program. After doing some research on some warnings, I damaged my Ruby and Rails installation. I uninstalled RVM, Ruby and Rails and messed up everything.

Opening a new terminal directly gives me:

```
Last login: Wed Aug 21 23:04:17 on ttys001
-bash: /Users/marcboehle/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
```

I tried to uninstall RVM, and everything else and wanted to start from scratch but with every new installation of RVM, Ruby and Rails it leads to the same errors.

The next thing is:

```
Upgrading the RVM installation in /usr/local/rvm/
Can not automatically remove lines with 'rvm_autolibs_flag=' from '/etc/rvmrc', please clean it manually.
Found 4800 directories with mode different then '775', use `--debug` to see the list, prefix the command with 'rvmsudo' to fix it, if the situation persist report a bug.
Found 18220 files with mode different then '664' or '775', use `--debug` to see the list, prefix the command with 'rvmsudo' to fix it, if the situation persist report a bug.
Upgrade of RVM in /usr/local/rvm/ is complete.




lab037:~ username$ rvm install
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin' is not at first place,
     usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
     it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
     to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p320'.
Can not use or install 'all' rubies.
```

Is there a good way to get rid of everything that's connected to Ruby, Rails and RVM and start from the beginning with a fresh installation? I can't figure out where `/etc/rvmrc` is.

Comment: When working with RVM, _ALWAYS_ read and reread the instructions on the [RVM site](https://rvm.io/). Those are the only true source for accurate and up-to-date information. RVM is well maintained and documented so there should be no need to look anywhere else than that site or follow directions from any other site. In my experience other sites are stale and/or ill-informed and often recommend things that are very wrong. If they ever mention using `sudo` back away quickly and reread the official site again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell problems that you're having come from `/Users/marcboehle/.profile` or `/Users/marcboehle/.bash_profile`.  Those will contain the directives for RVM.  For example here's mine:

```
brambook-pro-2:~ bram$ more ~/.bash_profile
export PATH=/Users/bram/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

You'll want to remove the `PATH` items that contain RVM,  then follow the [installation instructions](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) and see what you get.

Comment: thanks @Bramski , i found the file .bash_profile but not sure what to do with it now. this is what's in there: 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
source /Users/marcboehle/.rvm/scripts/rvm

##
# Your previous /Users/marcboehle/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/marcboehle/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2013-08-08_at_11:46:03
##
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-08-08_at_11:46:03: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH